# SQL inyection en Java con parámetros directos al Query!

Tags: java, sql

Tengo un TextBox que cuando obtengo su valor por get, y lo coloco en el Query directamente para hacer la consulta a la base de datos(MySql), me han dicho que es mala practica, como puedo solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es una mala práctica, no sé si te han explicado por qué, pero si en la `TextBox` escriben consultas SQL pueden hacerte denegación de servicios, borrar tablas, obtener datos...etc.

Supongo que ahora mismo haces las consultas con un `createStatement().executeQuery("consulta");`, y no es muy diferente, lo único que tienes que utilizar el método `preparedStatement('consulta')`:

```
  public class UnaClase {
   // Aqui guardamos un unico PreparedStatement para insertar 
   PreparedStatement psSelect = null;
   ...
   public void unMetodoDeInsertar () {
   try {
      // Creamos el PreparedStatement si no estaba ya creado. 
      if (null == psInsertar) { 
         psSelect = conexion.prepareStatement(
            "select * from tabla where condicion=?");
      ...
   } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Como verás, en el prepared statement hemos hecho una select en la que no le pasamos ningún valor, le pasamos una interrogación. Esa interrogación se sustituye de la siguiente manera:

```
psSelect.setString(1,TextBox1.getText);//Aquí pones como primer argumento la posición de la interrogación a reemplazar, en este caso es la primera(1), y después por lo que se va a reemplazar, en este caso lo que haya escrito en tu TextBox
```

Comment: gracias por tu aporte Calvo :)

Answer (score 4):

Debes usar [consultas preparadas JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) de la siguiente manera:

```
/* La conexión la tenemos definida en "con" y la cadena en "texto" */
PreparedStatement insertarStmt = null;
String insertString = "INSERT INTO tabla (texto) VALUES (?)";
try {
  con.setAutoCommit(false);
  insertarStmt = con.prepareStatement(insertString);
  /* Asignamos la variable "texto" al primer (y único) "?" de la consulta SQL */
  insertarStmt.setString(1, texto);
  /* Aunque se llame "executeUpdate" no implica que se use únicamente para
    actualizaciones es simplemente para indicar una consulta SQL que no
    tiene datos de retorno */
  insertarStmt.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
  /* ... */
} finally {
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte Oscar Garcia, de ahora en adelante a utilizar consultas preparadas para evitar sql inyection

Comment: @GiorgioMagaña No te olvides de marcar la respuesta como correcta.

Comment: intento marcar la respuesta como correcta pero me dice un mensaje que si no tengo mas de 15 puntos de reputación no puedo marcarla!

Comment: Gracias @Hechi . @GiorgioMagaña , Puedes marcar las respuestas ajenas como correctas desde el principio pulsando en la marca `✓` en color gris que aparece bajo los controles de votación positiva y negativa. Lo que no tienes permitido hasta que tengas 15 puntos es puntuar positiva o negativamente una respuesta. Si fuera una respuesta propia entonces deberías esperar 48 horas, pero también podrías.

Comment: nuevamente gracias por todo @os

Comment: De nada @GiorgioMagaña , ha sido un placer, aunque tengo que avisarte que has marcado como respuesta correcta la respuesta de otra persona, y no la mía :) agradecería que lo corrigieras, gracias.